# Tcp packets sent by socket via send() slow

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp, serversocket

I am trying to write an C/C++ application comunicating with a device using tcp socket. My app acts as a server socket.
When received data from device socket, server responses to device using send() function:

```
ssize_t send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
```

The buffer length (~4kB) is greater than MTU (1500 byte). TCP divide it to smaller packages. I used wireshark to capture packets. I saw that the time delay between tcp packets is 0.2-0.3s. If I send large data (~100Mb), it takes too long time (several hours). 
I have tried to setsockopt to enable TCP_NODELAY, TCP_QUICKACK and TCP_CORK but still cannot reduce the time delay.
Could you guys help me this issue? 
------------------- 
EDIT:
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void createServerSocket();
void acceptConnect(int serverSock);
void receiveDataFromSocket(int socket);
void sendDataOverSocket(int clientSock);

void createServerSocket() {
    int serverSockFd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    std::string address = "fd53:7cb8:383:5::68";
    int port = 42654;

    if (serverSockFd < 0)
    {
        printf("Create Server socket fail");
        return;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in6 serverAddress;
    (void)memset(&serverAddress, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in6));
    serverAddress.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    serverAddress.sin6_port = htons(port);
    int result = inet_pton(AF_INET6, address.c_str(), &serverAddress.sin6_addr);

    if (result <= 0)
    {
        printf("inet_pton() failed portnumber: %d, address: %s \n", port, address.c_str());
        return;
    }

    // setting socket options
    int flag = 1;

    if(setsockopt(serverSockFd,IPPROTO_TCP,TCP_QUICKACK  ,(char *)&flag,sizeof(flag)) == -1)
    {
        printf("setsockopt TCP_QUICKACK failed for server socket on address %s \n", address.c_str());
    }
    if(setsockopt(serverSockFd,IPPROTO_TCP,TCP_CORK,(char *)&flag,sizeof(flag)) == -1)
    {
        printf("setsockopt TCP_CORK failed for server socket on address %s \n", address.c_str());
    }
    if(setsockopt(serverSockFd,IPPROTO_TCP,TCP_NODELAY,(char *)&flag,sizeof(flag)) == -1)
    {
        printf("setsockopt TCP_NODELAY failed for server socket on address %s \n", address.c_str());
    }

    result = bind(serverSockFd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(sockaddr_in6));

    if (result != 0)
    {
        printf("bind() failed portnumber: %d, address: %s \n", port, address.c_str());
        return ;
    }

    result = listen(serverSockFd, 10);
    if (result != 0) {
        printf("listen() failed portnumber: %d, address: %s \n", port, address.c_str());
        return ;
    }

    acceptConnect(serverSockFd);
}

void acceptConnect(int serverSock)
{
    struct sockaddr_in6 clientAddress;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(sockaddr_in6);
    memset(&clientAddress, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in6));

    const int clientSocket = accept(serverSock, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddress, &len);

    if(clientSocket >= 0) {
        char str_addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(clientAddress.sin6_addr),
                  str_addr, sizeof(str_addr));
        printf("New connection from: %s:%d ...\n", str_addr, ntohs(clientAddress.sin6_port));
        receiveDataFromSocket(clientSocket);
    }
}

void receiveDataFromSocket(int socket)
{
    int SOCKET_BUFFER_MAX_SIZE = 8*1024;

    char buffer[SOCKET_BUFFER_MAX_SIZE];
    memset(buffer, '\0', SOCKET_BUFFER_MAX_SIZE);
    //Receive data from sock
    while (true) {
        int dataLen = recv(socket, buffer, SOCKET_BUFFER_MAX_SIZE, 0);
        printf("Receive data from socket: %d, msgLength = %d\n", socket, dataLen);
        sendDataOverSocket(socket);
    }
}

void sendDataOverSocket(int clientSock)
{
    int dataLen = 4*1024 + 7;
    char *buf = new char[dataLen];
    memset(buf, 'a', 4*1024 + 7);
    int ret;
    ret = send(clientSock, buf, dataLen, 0);

    if (ret <= 0) {
        printf("ERROR Send message over socket");
        return;
    }

    int error_code;
    socklen_t error_code_size = sizeof(sockaddr_in6);
    getsockopt(clientSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error_code, &error_code_size);
    printf("Error code size: %d, error code: %d\n", error_code_size, error_code);
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Make sure you are calling `send` the same number of times `recv` is called. In my experience, an imbalance between the two can result in much TCP slower performance.

Comment: `TCP_NODELAY` is the only one of those that would be useful to you.

Comment: You also don't tell us what the other device is. If it is some embedded controller thing, then you can expect it to be very slow. Some devices write responses to an SD card with horrible write speeds.

Comment: @Paul The number of send and the number of recv (or write and read) calls in TCP is irrelevant. TCP does not necessarily return bytes in the same size chunks as it was sent. You have to just read it until there's no more to read. Because it's a stream, not a datagram protocol.

Comment: @ZanLynx I was referring to the behavior described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274907/why-does-tcp-socket-slow-down-if-done-in-multiple-system-calls).

Comment: You may find [Jumbo frames](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame) interresting.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: I edited the post

Comment: @ZanLynx the problem is at my server side. As I mentioned in the post, I checked each tcp packet which sent from my app.

Comment: @Paul: I checked your link. Do I have to setsockopt TCP_NODELAY on clientSock, not the serverSock?

Comment: the send call may be blocking until it finishes...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are exceeding the TCP sending buffers, you are sequentially receiving and sending, if the other side is not reading data fast enough from the socket you will wait in every send() operation until you have space in your sending buffer.

Check if you are sending more information than receiving, I suspect recv() is reading small blocks (because the MTU) but you are sending about 4KB in every loop, so your recv/send calls are not properly balanced.

Comment: In device specification, it said that it happy receiving (4kB +7byte) data